# Fetch Gmail contacts in php

Tags: php, google-contacts-api, google-content-api

I want to get email ids which are associated to given gmail account. This should be done at local server, I am using `xampp server` on `Windows 7`.

I am using below link to get gmail contacts.

https://www.design19.org/blog/import-google-contacts-with-php-or-javascript-using-google-contacts-api-and-oauth-2-0/

Below steps I have done:

1. created project on google and also activate contact api.
2. paste `client_id` and `client_secret_id`.
3. `google_redirect_uri ='http://localhost';`

**Problem**

When ever I clicked on `import google contacts` button it redirect me to login page of google to Choose an account for login, after login site ask me to `Allow Contact shares` to do this?"

After clicking on allow button it redirect me to xampp's default index page `http://localhost/dashboard/` because in google app's redirect url I have set `http://localhost`.

I tried to set redirect url to contact api of google as per my files programs path but it not allowed me to use `/` so I have set it to :`http://localhost` in place of `http://localhost/contacts/index.php`

So where can I see response which I got from google contact api ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below mentioned steps.

> **Step 1:**

In your localhost application you need to set redirect URL as `http://localhost/contacts/index.php`

> **Step 2:**

In your Google App you need to add `http://localhost/contacts/index.php` in **Authorizes Redirect URL**.

Once you change this settings you can able to redirect on specific page.

Make sure your redirect URL in localhost Client call and In Google App both needs to be same else you will face error.

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: @AMITJOSHI: Glad to help you